# How to initialize different semantic-ui modules of the same type with different options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I have nested accordion modules and would like to initialize them differently, in this case to only open the inner accordion when its icon is clicked. It seems like the initialization can only happen once, though. Is there a way to change the options for the inner accordion?

This is the re-initialization that doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<div class="ui accordion main">
  <div class="title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Main 1
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="accordion sub">
      <div class="title">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Sub Title
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        Sub Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Main 2
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Main 2 Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion();
// $('.ui.accordion.main').accordion();  // Also doesn't work
$('.ui.accordion.sub').accordion({
  selector: {
    trigger: '.icon'
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7sdj9bd2/

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: @AlivetoDie The trigger is the default (the entire title) for both accordians